# Substitution of variable with term including unbound but used variable - refactor?

Tags: lambda-calculus, substitution

`λx.y[x:=y] == λx.y` since `x` is bound, no substitution happens. 
But what about `λx.y[y:=x]`? `y` is not bound, but if we perform the substitution then we get `λx.x`, but `λx.x` is not alpha-equivalent to the original `λx.y`. What do we do in this case? Can we refactor `λx.y[y:=x]` to `λx.y[y:=z]` and get `λx.z`, which is alpha equivalent to `λx.y`? Or is this a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The substitution, $(\lambda \color{blue}x.y)[y:=\color{green}x] = \lambda \color{blue}x.\color{green}x$ , is not *capture-avoiding* , because the variable $\color{blue}x$ is not *fresh* for the substituted term $\color{green}x$.   Thus it changes the meaning of the function.

So to preserve the meaning of the function, we do need to first alpha-replace with a fresh variable.

$(\lambda x.y)[y:=x] = (\lambda z.y)[y:=x] = \lambda z.x$

---

PS: "$t$ is fresh for $s$" means $t$ is not in the free variables of $s$.

Comment: Is the choice of renamed variable arbitrary? i.e. does `λx.y[y:=z] == λz.y[y:=x]` hold? If yes, is the latter preferred by convention?

Comment: No, that does not hold.  You must replace the term $y$ with the term $x$ in a manner which does not change the meaning of the lambda function.  Thus you alpha-replace the *variable* -- that which is bound to the scope of the lambda -- with a token which is *fresh* for the substitution *term*.  $$(\lambda x.y)[y:=x]\underbrace{ = \lambda z.(y[y:=x]) }_{z \text{ is fresh for term }x}= \lambda z.x$$

Comment: Thank you for the good explanations! Would +1 if I had the permission.